# guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes due application deployment to windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I've create a small app. It works fine on emulator and I want to test it on real device. So, I've created package using `"Menu->Store->Create App Package"` (I've tried both Release and Debug configurations).

Then I went to Application deployment tool and due deployment tool throw an error:

```
guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes.<br/>
System on device: Windows Phone 8.1<br/>
Package was generated for Windows Phone 8.1 (I have *.appx file)<br/>
```

I have no ideas how to find the place where I have problems with GUID. Could anybody help?

Comment: Be sure you use correct Visual Studio project. I got the same error if I tried to create app using DXperience Template Gallery. But after I created it using Templates - Visual C# - Store Apps - Windows Phone Apps, it worked well.